# rake db:seed not working in dev - pg is running but the connection is being refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to follow along on this tutorial and can't get past the setup of pg.
https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch

I set up pg on my computer using the postgres app, and I installed it successfully in my app using bundle install, but whenever I run rake db:seed I get the error below. pg is running on port 5432, I've tried uninstalling and installing again. rails server runs fine, and psql is working in the terminal.

I have been searching for hours and can't find anything that can explain what the issue is - most answers are to do with sunspot solr which I'm not using. I have already increased my system's shared memory as advised in the postgres app documentation:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=65536
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
```

I added the following to my development config as another answer mentioned this as a potential solution:

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false

Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is the error I get when I run rake db:seed

```
michaels-air:bookstore_search michaeltaylor$ rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/http/client.rb:19:in `post'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/index.rb:146:in `store'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:148:in `block in update_index'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4090249372457318285__update_elasticsearch_index__callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:144:in `update_index'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/model/callbacks.rb:21:in `block in included'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run__4090249372457318285__save__callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `create'
/Users/michaeltaylor/Codes/bookstore_search/db/seeds.rb:19:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/Codes/bookstore_search/db/seeds.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/Codes/bookstore_search/db/seeds.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:153:in `load_seed'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

This is my config yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: bookstore_development
  pool: 5
  username: michaeltaylor
  password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  host: localhost
```

This is what I get if I try and run rake db:setup

```
michaels-air:bookstore_search michaeltaylor$ rake db:setup --trace
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:schema:load_if_ruby (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
bookstore_development already exists
bookstore_test already exists
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:schema:load_if_ruby
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0194s
-- create_table("authors", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0214s
-- create_table("authors_books", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0075s
-- create_table("books", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0123s
-- create_table("books_subjects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0082s
-- create_table("subjects", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0092s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0029s
** Invoke db:structure:load_if_sql (first_time)
** Invoke db:create 
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:structure:load_if_sql
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/http/client.rb:19:in `post'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/index.rb:146:in `store'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:148:in `block in update_index'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1365093858615832810__update_elasticsearch_index__callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/model/search.rb:144:in `update_index'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tire-0.6.0/lib/tire/model/callbacks.rb:21:in `block in included'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run__1365093858615832810__save__callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:299:in `create_or_update'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `create'
/Users/michaeltaylor/Codes/bookstore_search/db/seeds.rb:19:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/Codes/bookstore_search/db/seeds.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/Codes/bookstore_search/db/seeds.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:153:in `load_seed'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/michaeltaylor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
```

Comment: Are you able to access your database in rails console? It sets up fine when you run `rake db:create db:migrate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like a Postgres issue. Judging by the stack trace, apparently you need to start your ElasticSearch server.